# Why is `ls hello.txt | cat` different from `cat hello.txt`?

Tags: linux, pipe, cat, ls

I wonder why `ls hello.txt|cat` does not do the same thing as `cat 
hello.txt`?   I am trying to pass the result of `ls` to `cat`, which seems to make sense, because the result of 'ls hello.txt' is hello.txt itself.

Comment: `ls` stands for `list`, `cat` is short for `concatenate`. Why would you expect them to be the same? (`ls` lists file information (e.g. size, ownership), `cat` concatenates file (default to `stdout`). If your system default for `ls` adds additional options (e.g. --color), then they will not be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pipe in input to `cat`, the result is the input.  That's how `cat` handles stdin.  In general, programs are supposed to treat stdin differently than they treat arguments.

Maybe these can help you see it a bit clearer:

```
echo "hello" | cat
=> hello
```

`echo "hello"` feeds in "hello" to `cat`, and `cat`'s behavior with stdin is just to print out whatever it receives in stdin.  So it prints out "hello".

```
cat hello.txt | cat
=> prints out the text of hello.txt
```

The first `cat` outputs the contents of `file.txt`, and the second `cat` outputs whatever it receives in stdin -- `file.txt`'s contents.

So, what does `ls hello.txt` output?

`ls hello.txt` doesn't output the text inside `hello.txt`.  Instead, it literaly just outputs the string `"hello.txt"` if the file exists:

```
ls hello.txt
=> hello.txt

ls hello.txt | cat
=> hello.txt
```

just like how:

```
echo "hello"
=> hello

echo "hello" | cat
=> hello
```

I guess maybe one of the big misunderstandings might be that you're thinking `ls hello.txt` outputs the *contents* of `hello.txt`...but it doesn't, it just outputs the name.  And `cat` takes in that name, and prints the name right back out.  The **result** of `ls hello.txt` is literally just the string "hello.txt"...it's not the contents of the file.  And `cat` just outputs what it receives -- the string "hello.txt".  (not the contents of the file)

Comment: Kudos - a great explanation :)  You're absolutely correct!

Answer (score 1):

The command    `ls hello.txt|cat` is little ambiguous because you are passing the results of ls command by putting pipe(|) what you want to do can be achieved by

```
ls hello.txt|xargs cat
```

What I can figure out is that ls is giving output as standard input to cat while cat expects filename as an argument.

An alternate way to achieve is by

```
cat $(ls hello.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks. But indeed I am trying to pass the result of ls to cat. Why that is not right, given that the result of 'ls hello.txt' is hello.txt?

Comment: @zell: Because `cat` doesn't read a list of files to read from `stdin`, it just makes `stdin` the file to read if you don't specify a different one.  So `ls` prints the word "hello.txt" to its `stdout`, which goes through the pipe and becomes the `stdin` of `cat`.  Since `cat` is printing out its stdin (you haven't specified a different file), it obediently prints the word "hello.txt" out.

Comment: No: `cat $(ls hello.txt)` != `ls hello.txt|cat`.  The output happens to look the same; what's actually happening at the shell level is completely different.

Comment: @paulsm4 I have suggested an alternate way , my second code is actually the original answer.

Comment: @paulsm4 Why not? Could you elaborate a bit as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

1. David C. Rankin and  Ben Voigt are both correct.
2. `cat hello.txt` writes the output of the file "hello.txt" to stdout (e.g. to your command prompt.
3. `ls hello.txt` writes the value "hello.txt" to stdout.  `cat`, with no arguments, reads from it's stdin (instead of parsing a command line argument).  Consequently, `ls hello.txt | cat` does the following:

   a. The shell executes "ls hello.txt" and generates the output "hello.txt".

   b. The shell then creates a pipe to a second command, "cat", and directs "hello.txt" to cat's stdin.

   c. "cat" reads stdin and outputs the value of file "hello.txt" to it's stdout.